# How do I describe the a type in typescript that has dynamic name?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I want to describe a type that has the following behavior

```
export class myData {
    key          : string;
    display_name : string;  
}
```

However I want to have dynamic name for `key` and `display_name` with the actual key and display_name that I supplied

eg. the following would be valid myData type

```
mySample1:myData =
{ 
    myKey    : 'myKeyValue'
    myName   : 'myNameValue'
}

mySample1:myData =
{ 
    myKey2    : 'myKeyValue2'
    myName2   : 'myNameValue2'
}
```

The motivation for this is that I have alot of data from API that returns a list of object with same number of key and with same type of value for each key. But the thing is that each data has different key names.

I want to create a `Component` in angular2 that only takes a list of object with certain number of keys, and each key's value have to be a certain type.

For example I don't want my `Component` to take

```
var test =
{ 
    myKey2    : 1
    myName2   : 'myNameValue2'
}
```

or

```
var test2 =
{ 
    myKey2    : 'myNameValue1'
    myName2   : 'myNameValue2'
    mySomeOtherKey : 'myNameValue10'
}
```

Is this possible in typescript? If it is possible, is this a good idea in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

> eg. the following would be valid myData type

TypeScript is structural. Since you want both of these to be *valid*:

```
mySample1:myData =
{ 
    myKey    : 'myKeyValue'
    myName   : 'myNameValue'
}

mySample1:myData =
{ 
    myKey2    : 'myKeyValue2'
    myName2   : 'myNameValue2'
}
```

You can easily declare `myData` to be a *union* of these two types:

```
type MyData = {
    myKey: string;
    myName: string;
}
    | {
        myKey2: string;
        myName2: string;
    }

let mySample1: MyData =
    {
        myKey: 'myKeyValue',
        myName: 'myNameValue'
    }

mySample1 =
    {
        myKey2: 'myKeyValue2',
        myName2: 'myNameValue2'
    }
```